# waiting after meat, in contexts other than basar bechalav

Tags: halacha, time, meat-and-milk, meat

Waiting after meat before milk comes from a concern of either the taste being still in your throat or particles still in your teeth and you are eating that with milk.  Do we apply this in other cases as well?  I can think of lots of other potential applications.

For example, if you eat chametz meat (not just cooked in a chametz pot, I'm thinking something like chicken with breadcrumbs) on the morning of erev Pesach, and it's now after the time when you can't eat chametz but your 6/5+/3/1 hours have not yet elapsed, are you allowed to eat anything?

Or similarly, if you accidentally eat meat that's not kosher, do you have to wait before eating anything?

Or if you eat a korban close to the end of its time period and it's now after that time, do you have to wait before eating anything else?

Comment: I'll one-up you: Are you allowed to eat _chametz_ meat immediately before the prohibition time at all, considering that we are worried about remnants in your teeth?

Comment: @msh210 I hope so.  Otherwise how will people who wait 6 hours eat the Pesach?  It's about 6 hours from shkiya to chatzot, and by the time you get up to tzafun...

Comment: even 3 hours might be cutting it close

Comment: Meet and chametz have their own halachos. I don't see a connection just bc the chametz was on the chicken. Why should chametz in your teeth have the same amount of time to be removed as the meat? Can you source this connection?

Comment: @Dude see Tosfot Chullin 108b at the top, he discusses whether or not חתיכה נעשית נבלה means you apply the chumrot of both substances on top of each other.  According to Rabbeinu Shmuel, this chicken that was cooked with chametz becomes chametz itself but simultaneously keeps its identity as chicken.  According to the Ri you're right, this particular case doesn't work.  The question is still valid for the other cases though.  As I remember the other rishonim there talk about this too.

Comment: I would think to say that the problem between meat and milk specifically is the conbination of the two tastes, while by any other issur, there is no combination that becomes asur only after being combined. Either the chametz in your teeth is a problem all by itself or it isn't.

Comment: @ShmuelKoppel then how about waiting between pesach sheini and chametz?