# Is it permitted to eat dairy after eating non-kosher meat?

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk

This is referring to eating meat from a kosher animal that was not shechted. [Rambam (Ma'achalot Asurot 9:6)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Foods.9.6?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that there is a prohibition to cook them together but there is no prohibition to eat them together. Presumably he is referring to the Torah issur of eating milk and meat cooked together. The question here is if there is rabbinical prohibition on eating dairy **after** eating this meat.

Perhaps this would depend on whether the rabbinical prohibition is contingent on there being a Torah level prohibition on eating them together (which is not the case here), or perhaps they forbade it since there is a prohibition to cook them together.

A well-sourced answer would be appreciated.

Not sure if this the place to add this (my apologies to the moderators.) As opposed to the Mor VeOhalot who is stringent [Minchat Yitzchak](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1601&st=&pgnum=106&hilite=) permits this (9:79 end of Aleph).

Comment: We have a rule that the chachomim didnt make laws for sinners.

Comment: @interested it could have been pikuach nefesh to eat the meat but not to eat the dairy

Comment: There is no Torah level prohibition on eating dairy with chicken, but common practice is to wait after chicken as well.

Comment: @Heshy And maybe now you can't eat anything https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70650/759

Comment: @interested nice insight, thank you. Even though it's possible for this to happen without sinning, such as pikuach nefesh which was mentioned, or it was eaten by accident, (or it turned out to be a treifa?) chazal don't make takanot on situations that are not common. Unless we would say "lo plug".

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03GpyipKfdi_uX26Sg4DwwxfIY4Tw%3A1598557746283&source=hp&ei=Mg5IX4GUDommULjej7AP&q=תקנתא+לרשיעי&oq=תקנתא+לרשיעי&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABOgQIIxAnOggIABCxAxCDAToCCC46AggAOgQIABAeOgQIABABOgYIABAKEAE6BggAEBYQHjoHCCEQChCgAVDdG1ijVWCvamgAcAB4AYABdYgBvAiSAQQxMi4ymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiB9ffUk7zrAhUJExQKHTjvA_YQ4dUDCAg&uact=5

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10710/170

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Darkei Teshuva (Munkatch) 89:1 brings that if it one eats basar neveilah (not slaughtered correctly) or treifah (fatal defect) bshogeg, then they would need to wait, but if they ate basar timeiah (non-kosher species) bshogeg, then no waiting is necessary.

Text of Darkei Teushva:

[image]

Comment: This is a link to what is cited, bottom of the right column. Thank you very much. https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=319&st=&pgnum=78&hilite=

Comment: Seems like Minchat Yitzchak 9:79 (end of Aleph) permits this https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=319&st=&pgnum=78&hilite=